# Flextable Selectors: Making a function for the i and j arguments

Tags: r, function, expression, flextable

As noted in [2.4 selectors of the flextable vignette](https://ardata-fr.github.io/flextable-book/design.html#selectors), often we would want to conditionally add formatting to a flextable. The following example is from the flextable vignette: https://ardata-fr.github.io/flextable-book/design.html

```
library(flextable)
dat <- head(ggplot2::diamonds, n = 10)
ft <- qflextable(dat) 

color(ft,
~ price < 330, color = "orange", ~ price + x + y + z 
)  

color(
  ft,
  i = ~ cut %in% "Premium", 
  j = ~ x + y, 
color = "red"
)
```

As the dataset varies, I want to make the selection of **cut** above as a function.

```
#'@param x A flextable
#'@param t Text within the dataset x
f <- function(x, t)  x %>% color(i = ~ cut %in% t, j = ~ x + y,  color = "red")

f(ft, "Premium")
# Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) : 
'match' requires vector arguments
```

I wonder how the flexible selection handle arguments passed into expression. Is there a way to make a function that works similar to adding the text itself.

Exploring a little deeper, a function like color passes the condition to internal `get_row_id()` to internal `get_i_from_formula()`. The error occurs in evaluating the call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stefan points out your formula is not capturing the argument t (instead it assumes it's refering to the function [`t`](https://search.r-project.org/R/refmans/base/html/t.html).

Alternatively, you can inject the parameter with `rlang`:

```
f <- function(x, t) rlang::inject(
  x %>% color(i = ~ cut %in% !!t, j = ~ x + y,  color = "red"))

f(ft, "Premium")
```

Comment: Nice. Will keep that one in mind. +1

Comment: This idea also works with numbers as well. `r f <- function(ft, threshold){
  rlang::inject(
    color(ft,
          ~ price < !!threshold, color = "orange", ~ price + x + y + z 
    ) 
  )
}
` `f(ft, 330)`

Answer (score 2):

As formulas are used to select rows and columns my guess is that the `t` in your formula is not replaced by the value of the function argument `t`. One option to fix that would be to create the formula as a string and convert it to a proper formula using e.g. `as.formula`. Note that to make this work one has to manually "add" quotes to the character string `t` using `"\""`.

```r
library(flextable)

dat <- head(ggplot2::diamonds, n = 10)
ft <- qflextable(dat) 

f <- function(x, t)  {
  t <- paste0("\"", t, "\"")
  fml <- as.formula(paste("~ cut %in%", t))
  color(x, i = fml, j = ~ x + y,  color = "red")
}

f(ft, "Premium")
```

[image]